# Sending emails SMTP C# .NET Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, smtp, windows-10

I have written an application for email sending on C# .NET (2.0) (needs for using on old PCs). All worked normally on the Windows 7. When I had started to use Windows 10, I faced with this problem. I'm receiving the error:

> "Failure sending e-mail". I'm using the Gmal email box. SMTP-port:
>   587, SMTP server: smtp.gmail.com, SSL enabled.

Why is this problem arised? And how can I solve it? Thank you!

UPD:
Guys! I have searched the reason. My computer name was 'Дмитрий-PC' (I'm Russian and there was russian letters in the name). When I had changed the name all was OK (Dmitry-PC). But please give me advice how can I avoid these mistakes in the future because many people in my country might have the Pc name.with rus letters. Maybe by XML? I don't know.

Comment: This may not be related to windows 10. Gmail does not allow you to send emails using its smtp for extended periods. I think you app has been blocked. Try to use [fake smtp](https://nilhcem.github.io/FakeSMTP/) and test it.

Comment: Have you enabled 'lower security' apps to connect to the google account?

Comment: Are the Windows firewall settings different between 7 & 10?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved by using XML in `app.config`:

```
<configuration>
    <system.net>
      <mailSettings>
        <smtp>
          <network clientDomain="name"/>
        </smtp>
      </mailSettings>
    </system.net>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to send emails via SMTP from Google you need to enable less secure apps to connect to the Google Account.

Check [this](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) article out on how to enable less secure apps.

If that doesn't work you need to also verify that you have `.NET 2.0` installed on your Windows 10 machine. You can download it [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1639) if you don't have it

Comment: I don't understand how this setting would change behaviour between windows 7 & 10

Comment: Valid point. Could be that in Windows 10 he doesn't have `.NET 2.0`

Comment: Guys! I have searched the reason. My computer name was 'Дмитрий-PC' (I'm Russian and there was russian letters in the name). When I had changed the name all was OK (Dmitry-PC). But please give me advice how can I avoid these mistakes in the future because many people in my country might have the Pc name.with rus letters. Maybe by XML? I don't know.